# PHP - How to get data from database which is in another pc?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

A quick question. I have two laptops, installed with WAMP, both using MYSQL.

1. I tried ping each other -> success
2. Configure the phpmyadmin -> require and allow ip addresses ->success
3. View phpmyadmin of another pc typing 192.168.0.*->succes

But when i tried to putting php code on laptop A with '192.168.0.*' as host , it came out an error, saying server not responding, run time error...

Comment: Did you try executing GRANT qauery with 192.168.0 and credentials to give privileage?

Comment: Are you starring out your local ip address (really?) or is that actually what you're trying to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the following line in the mysql configuration file. And make sure the privilege is there for the user.

```
bind-address=YOUR-SERVER-IP
```